# how can I use xml-rpc-c to transfer a jpg on the internet

Tags: xml-rpc

Now the the situation is like this:with the help of xml-rpc-c, I can transfer char and int, but now I want to transfer some binary data. I use char* to record the binary data, and then I use fomatstring "s#" or "6", they all couldn't work, the error is "4-byte supposed UTF-8 string is not valid UTF-8. Unrecognized UTF-8 initial byte value 0xffffffff(-510)" . Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the it into Base64. There are a lot available of libraries depending upon your development stack. Images encoded into Base64 will be larger that the original image, so use it if it is really necessary.